# About the trace class operators and their motivation

Tags: operator-theory

What is the motivation for trace class operators? Can anybody suggest the most general and standard reference that includes Schatten $p$ class operators as well?
I have the following references.

> 1. Operator theory by Conway
> 2. Operator theory in function spaces by Kehe Zhu

Can anybody suggest even better?

Comment: Also seen at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150915/about-the-trace-class-operators-and-their-motivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [*Trace Ideals and Their Applications*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849883) by Barry Simon. He covers the general theory of Schatten ideals and their applications, with particular attention to applications in quantum physics.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix Analysis by Rajendra Bhatia

Comment: Does this cover infinite dimensions? (The notion of "trace class" is trivial in finite dimensions)

Comment: I donot remember it, but The Homology of Banach and Topological Algebras by A. Ya. Helemskii will be helpful for you.